# custom UIButton shadow

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, calayer

i have rounded rect UIButton and want to add shadow to it, but when i set the background image shadow is not visible, i think background overlays the shadow. without background image shadow is visible

```
customBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    customBtn.frame=CGRectMake(customBtn.frame.origin.x, customBtn.frame.origin.y, 30, 30);
     [customBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [customBtn setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    customBtn.layer.cornerRadius=9;

 customBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    customBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    customBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    customBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0f, 2.0f);
customBtn.clipsToBounds=YES;
```

Comment: try removing clipToBounds=YES (or set it to NO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the internal structure of `UIButton`, your best bet is to create a stretchable background image which includes the shadow.

```
UIImage *bgWithShadow = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"bg.png"] 
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 10 
                                                topCapHeight: 0];
[customBtn setBackgroundImage: bgWithShadow 
                     forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

This example assumes that `bg.png` is a 21-pixels wide image which includes a shadow. Basically, you don't have to do anything else like accessing the button's layer or changing its `clipsToBounds` property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671315/using-resizableimagewithcapinsets-image-for-button-only-works-for-the-state-set) to get an idea of what a stretchable image is (with pictures!).

Note that `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:` is being deprecated in favor of `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.