# UIButton with title adjusts image when highlighted abnormally

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a button with 1) a title 2) a background image, but it adjusts image abnormally when highlighted. It has white area in the middle. Any one help?

```
_cancelButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
_cancelButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
UIImage *cancelImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"search_cancel_btn.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0 , 11, 0, 11)];
[_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:cancelImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cancelButton setTitle:@"取消" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_cancelButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
[_cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:0xff666666] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(264, 9.5, 52, 32)];
[_cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doCancel) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_topSearchView addSubview:_cancelButton];
```

[image: abnormal highlighted image]

Comment: resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0 , 11, 0, 11) why have u used this...

Comment: because search_cancel_btn.png is only 22 pix width, i wanna resize it

Comment: _cancelButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO would remove the highlighted white area in the middle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using resizableImageWithCapInsets: image for button only works for the state set, other states show a "gap"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671315/using-resizableimagewithcapinsets-image-for-button-only-works-for-the-state-set)

Comment: @jrturton,thanks for the link, it solves my problem. i have searched in this site but not found it.

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with adding these lines to the same code:

```
    _cancelButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:cancelImg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_cancelButton setTitle:@"取消" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [_cancelButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHex:0xff666666] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```